# What is this naming convention called?

Tags: history, names, surnames

Many historical figures (of antiquity) have names of the form "X the Y". Some real, historical examples are:

- [Wayland the Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_the_Smith)
- [William the Conquerer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_the_Conqueror)
- [Attila the Hun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attila)

This concept has also made its way into popular culture also. For instance, the Skyrim character [Vekel the Man](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Vekel_the_Man).

**What is this naming convention called?** I can imagine there's a word bearing the "-ym" suffix for this concept, but I've never for the life of me been able to find it.

Comment: I'd say so! I wouldn't have ever thought of "epithet" given my encounters with that word have been in exclusively negative contexts.

Comment: According to Göran Kjellmer's [article](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00138387708597859?journalCode=nest20) "Why is Winnie *The* pooh? On the use of the definite article in some English personal names" (Eng. Stud. vol. 58, pp. 508-514, 1977), this is a remnant of not one, but several distinct historical practices. As a consequence, it doesn't have a unique name. Calling it all 'epithet' is misleading, and this question should not have been closed.

Comment: I'm open to reopening this (pun unintentional), but in all fairness, the linked question *does* describe what I was initially after. Wikipedia seems to somewhat agree.